# How do browsers "link" the saved web page and the folder which containes its resources (js/css/images etc.)?

Tags: html, browser, save

I tried searching online (Google, and StackOverflow) for it but couldn't find anything, so I'd like to ask, how exactly do browsers, when saving a web page (*as Complete WebPage*) link/connect the HTML file with the folder that contains its resources (*images/js/css*) so that whenever the file is moved and/or copied, the folder gets moved and/or copied with it?

Further, is there any way to attain this effect programmatically? (Preferably, C#).

Thanks.